# Create an irregular 3D geometry from a cloud of points

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a large set of 3D points which are equally spaced in each axis. Many of these points are culled based on some criteria, and I'd like to create a 3D geometry to help visualize what's left.

I have looked at some algorithms to create a triangle mesh such as Delaunay Triangulations or a convex hull, but I'm worried that some excluded points might get caught inside the geometry. For example, a 2D slice might look like:

```
0 0 0 1 1 0 0   
0 0 1 1 1 1 0   
0 1 1 1 1 1 1   
1 1 0 1 0 1 1   
0 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

Where "1"s are included and "0"s are excluded. In this case I'm worried that the algorithm will accidentally include the "0"s on the bottom rows because they have "1"s bordering them on both sides. Note that the "0"s will always be on the edge, so we don't have to worry about holes in the geometry.

Afterwards, I will need to be able to rotate the geometry and find its intersection with a plane. I'm pretty sure I can handle the rotation and intersection part, but please keep that in mind.

I could brute force the problem by creating every triangle possible for all points on the surface, and then manually culling out any triangles that contain an excluded point. But the data set can be very large, so I hope there's a more elegant solution to this.

Comment: Have a look at 3D alpha-shapes.

Comment: I don't think alpha-shapes make any effort to avoid my excluded points. If I understand it correctly, a large alpha value risks capturing my excluded points, and a small alpha value is back to brute force triangulation.

Comment: You can get it done in `O(I)` if you treat the point set as a 3D grid graph, where I is the number of included points. A 3D exterior walk should be able to do it whether you seek a mesh or a triangulation. If you already have the points setup to allow for O(1) checking if a given point is interior or exterior, then a mesh can be done in better than `O(I)`. Also, alpha shapes will probably work if you chose the right alpha, which I'm thinking is in the range of `1/(G*k) <= alpha <= 1/(G/k)`, where `1 <= k < 2`, G is the grid spacing size. Recommend trying  `alpha = 1/G, 1/(G/1.5), 1/(G * 1.5)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in closed geometries and each are on a plane do you need a mesh/triangualtion or simply a set of polygons?

Converting the 0,1 data into a binary image and running a contour algorithm on would be very simple see [OPENCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv)

Comment: I think the OP is looking for full triangulation of a point cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [Point Cloud Library](http://www.pointclouds.org/about/).

Comment: I've downloaded and installed PCL, but I haven't had enough time to look through it yet. But it looks like PCL is just using convex hulls and alpha shapes.